# Append/prepend permalink with meta values in custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

How to append meta values to custom post types in permalink?
I have urls like `www.abc.com`
and along with post title, I want to add two meta values, namely Date as year/month & name of company in the custom type post permalink.

So, my finaly permalink I am expecting is like this :

```
www.abc.com/2018/04/best-car-this-year-Honda
```

Tried many links before this , none worked perfectly.

```
add_action('init', 'Theme2035_detail_register');
//Registering new custom post type - Detail

function Theme2035_detail_register() {    

    $ldate ='/'; // to remove post type from permalink 
    $labels = array(
        'add_new' => __('Add New Detail', 'espresso'),          
        'name' => __('Detail','espresso'),     
        'singular_name' => __('Detail', 'espresso'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Detail', 'espresso'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Detail Item', 'espresso'),
        'new_item' => __('New Detail', 'espresso'),
        'view_item' => __('View Detail', 'espresso'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Detail', 'espresso'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Detail have been added yet', 'espresso'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'espresso'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(  
        'labels' => $labels,  
        'public' => true,  
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,        
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $ldate, 'with_front' => false ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail','comments'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
        'menu_icon'  => 'dashicons-format-office',
       );  

    register_post_type( 'detail' , $args );  
}
```

My post title is Best Car this year, So here as you can see my default custom page url is coming like this :

```
www.abc.com/best-car-this-year
```

And what I am trying to get is append a date before the custom post title in permalink and a brand name after the permalink. It would look like this :

```
www.abc.com/2018/04/best-car-this-year_HONDA
```

The date can be added on date and the Brand name would be fetched from post meta table.

Comment: I tried filter action, but I could not get a stable solution,It redirects no where, end with server loop. Sorry I am a beginner in wordpress.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's not clear. Please also show us what you've tried

Comment: Ok I have edited the question to make you understand it in a better way, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of solutions, which can be used for building url structure as we want. Here is one of working solutions to get the url structure like `www.abc.com/2018/04/best-car-this-year_HONDA`:

```
add_action('init', 'Theme2035_detail_register');
function Theme2035_detail_register() {

    $ldate ='/%detail_year%/%detail_monthnum%';
    $labels = array(
        'add_new' => __('Add New Detail', 'espresso'),
        'name' => __('Detail','espresso'),
        'singular_name' => __('Detail', 'espresso'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Detail', 'espresso'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Detail Item', 'espresso'),
        'new_item' => __('New Detail', 'espresso'),
        'view_item' => __('View Detail', 'espresso'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Detail', 'espresso'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Detail have been added yet', 'espresso'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'espresso'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $ldate, 'with_front' => false),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail','comments'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
        'menu_icon'  => 'dashicons-format-office',
    );

    register_post_type( 'detail' , $args );
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'ww_construct_permalink', 1, 2);
function ww_construct_permalink( $permalink, $post ){
    $year_mask = '%detail_year%';
    $month_mask = '%detail_monthnum%';
    if( strpos($permalink, $year_mask) === false && strpos($permalink, $month_mask) === false ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $year = date("Y", strtotime($post->post_date));
    $month = date("m", strtotime($post->post_date));

    return str_replace([$year_mask,$month_mask], [$year, $month], $permalink );
}
```

Our steps:

1. Your variable `$ldate` we defined as `/%detail_year%/%detail_monthnum%`, instead of which we can use anything like `%anything%`. But we need to be sure that it'll not be overriden with some other plugin/theme, which may use same variant.
2. We used [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) filter for creating the url we want, and after checking the `$year_mask` and `$month_mask` to be sure, that the post type is our created, we getting the created date of our post from `WP_Post object` and returning the url structure we want.

NOTE: May be need to flush your permalinks by opening `Dashboard -> Permalinks -> Save`( without changing something ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code.

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'cpt_permalink_change', 10, 2 );
function cpt_permalink_change( $args, $post_type ) 
{   
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'your permalink';
    return $args;
}//end of function
```

Hope this will work for you.